# Problem while trying to replace outliers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, outliner

Okay, so I've trying to clean data for the Machine Learning project. I'm using Z-Score for the outliers detection. Database contains different types of glass (from 1-7) and I want to go through each glass type, find the outliers and replace them with mean values of the sodium contained in a given type of glass ("Na" column). The weird thing is the algorithm is working for glass Type 1 and 2 but when it comes to Type 3 it gives a ValueError. Do you guys know what seems to be the problem?

```
z = stats.zscore(DataFrame.Na)
threshold = 1.99

for t in DataFrame.Type.unique():
    z = stats.zscore(DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t])
    print([DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t][(np.abs(z) > threshold)]])
    DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t] = DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t].replace([DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t][(np.abs(z) > threshold)]],np.mean(DataFrame.Na[DataFrame.Type==t]))
```

And the output is:

```
[17    14.36
21    14.77
Name: Na, dtype: float64]
[70     14.86
105    11.45
106    10.73
108    14.43
110    11.23
111    11.02
Name: Na, dtype: float64]
[149    12.16
Name: Na, dtype: float64]

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2897             try:
-> 2898                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2899             except KeyError as err:

KeyError: 0
```

Any of you guys know what could be wrong with this? If you need any additional information I will provide it, thinking about this for about 2 hours and I don't have a clue...

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I'll post my comment as an answer.

Are you trying to detect "outliers" or "outliners". Not just being pedantic here as they are different statistical concepts.

Comment: Yeah, you are right I meant outliers. Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that somewhere you are trying to set the value at row 0 in a dataframe that does not have a row 0. Try breaking up your long lines, and printing the results to console, you'll likely find the error that way.

Comment: Okey, so I did what you've said. I printed each element separately and weird thing is that each element gives an value and looks like everything is okay with it.
And the output for Type 3 is:
`[False False False  True False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False]
13.437058823529412 - mean Value,
[149    12.16` - location of outlier in DF
So it finds which value is an outlier, counts the mean value (13.43), and where this outlier is located in DataFrame but still gives KeyError 0 when I'm trying to combine this in a single line of code.